# Move two captions to the top and to the left respectively

Tags: tables, spacing, horizontal-alignment, captions

I have two captions in the following table:

```
\begin{table}[!htbp]
\caption{Stuff Stuff Stufff.}
\begin{tabular}{l |l  l| l}
\hline
  & aaaaaaa  & aaaaaaa & aaaaaaaa \\ \hline
bbbbbbb & bbbbbbbb & bbbbbbbb  & bbbbbbb \\ 
ccccccccccc & cccccccccc & cccccccccc  & cccccccccc \\ 
dddddddddd & dddddddddd & dddddddddd  & ddddddddd \\
eeeeeeeeeee & eeeeeeeeee & eeeeeeeeeee  & eeeeeeeeeee \\ \hline
fffffffffff & ffffffffff & ffffffffff  & fffffffffff \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption*{Stuff Stuff Stuff.}
\end{table}
```

I am trying to move the top caption a bit vertically, and the bottom caption to the left. Is this possible?

Comment: Is [this your current output](http://i.stack.imgur.com/cd49a.png) and [this is what you're after](http://i.stack.imgur.com/kevX4.png)?

Comment: @Werner I changed the table to make it clearer. The issue is that everything is centered, but the bottom caption needs to be moved to the left bottom corner of the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The vertical gap between the caption and the float content can be specified via the `skip=<len>` option from [`caption`](http://ctan.org/pkg/caption). Alternatively, you can specify it manually inside the float using `\vspace`.

You can move the lower caption to the left of the `tabular` by setting it in an appropriately-matching `\multicolumn`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{skip=2\baselineskip}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
  \centering
  \caption{Stuff Stuff Stufff.}
  %\vspace{2\baselineskip}% Gap between caption and float content
  \begin{tabular}{l |l  l| l}
    \hline
    & aaaaaaa  & aaaaaaa & aaaaaaaa \\ \hline
    bbbbbbb & bbbbbbbb & bbbbbbbb  & bbbbbbb \\ 
    ccccccccccc & cccccccccc & cccccccccc  & cccccccccc \\ 
    dddddddddd & dddddddddd & dddddddddd  & ddddddddd \\
    eeeeeeeeeee & eeeeeeeeee & eeeeeeeeeee  & eeeeeeeeeee \\ \hline
    fffffffffff & ffffffffff & ffffffffff  & fffffffffff \\ \hline
    \multicolumn{4}{l}{Stuff Stuff Stuff.}
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

---

Perhaps you'd be interested in a [`booktabs`](http://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs) via of your `tabular`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{caption,booktabs}
\captionsetup{skip=2\baselineskip}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
  \centering
  \caption{Stuff Stuff Stufff.}
  \begin{tabular}{ *{4}{l} }
    \toprule
    & aaaaaaa  & aaaaaaa & aaaaaaaa \\
    \midrule
    bbbbbbb & bbbbbbbb & bbbbbbbb  & bbbbbbb \\ 
    ccccccccccc & cccccccccc & cccccccccc  & cccccccccc \\ 
    dddddddddd & dddddddddd & dddddddddd  & ddddddddd \\
    eeeeeeeeeee & eeeeeeeeee & eeeeeeeeeee  & eeeeeeeeeee \\
    \midrule
    fffffffffff & ffffffffff & ffffffffff  & fffffffffff \\
    \bottomrule
    \multicolumn{4}{l}{\footnotesize Stuff Stuff Stuff.}
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

No vertical rules are necessary, of course.

Comment: Thanks. Can you column lines? and all of the same intensity?

Comment: @Cauchy: I don't understand. The intent of [`booktabs`](http://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs), as mentioned in its [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/booktabs/booktabs.pdf), is to avoid "column lines".